# A non well formed numeric value encountered

Tags: php

i have some problem with my syntax, this is my syntax:

```
for($x=1;$x<=12;$x++){
    $date_a=strtotime("+ $x month", $a['date_start']);                          
    $end=date('d-m-Y',$date_a);

}
```

then appears error A non well formed numeric value encountered in this  `$date_a=strtotime("+ $x month", $a['date_start']);`

anyone can help me?

Comment: Is `$a['date_start']` a timestamp?

Comment: $a['date_start'] is a date type

Comment: `strtotime` second parameter must be a timestamp. I assume it isn't.

Comment: Can you show what is in `$a['date_start']`? Then we will able to give you the correct answer.

Comment: See AbraCadaver answer then it will help you.

Comment: You code works with a valid timestamp [**demo**](https://eval.in/125308)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't shown `$a['date_start']` but if it is a valid date format that can be converted to a timestamp, try:

```
$date_a = strtotime("+ $x month", strtotime($a['date_start']));
```

Or do it once up front:

```
$start = strtotime($a['date_start']);

for($x=1;$x<=12;$x++){
    $date_a = strtotime("+ $x month", $start);                          
    $end = date('d-m-Y', $date_a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you write "+ $x month"and it doesn't recognize $x is a variable.

Try writing "+ " .$x. " month" instead.